# How to represent a factorial programmatically

Tags: java, output, factorial

I couldn't find a proper title.

I wrote a tiny program to calculate the factorial of a given integer. The program works fine as expected. Now I would like to also print its representation, say we have 4 as input, the program would output 24 and then print `Because 4! = 4 x 3 x 2 x 1`.

```
public class Test {
    static int factorial(int n){    
        if (n == 0)    
            return 1;    
        else    
            return(n * factorial(n-1));    
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i;
        int fact;
        int number= sc.nextInt();//Get user input and calculate its factorial    
        fact = factorial(number);   
        System.out.println("Factorial of " + number + " is " + fact);
        System.out.println("Because " + number+"!" + " = " + number + "x" + (number - 1) ); // This is what I tried so far
    } 
}
```

The last `println` shows what I have tried. However, I'm only able to output `4! = 4 x 3`, unable to go down to 1.

Comment: I think this is a factorial expansion.

Comment: It’s unclear what your problem is. Note that you not making a reasonable attempt (ie printing 2 numbers) is not the kind of  “problem” this site caters for: This site is not a code writing service. Try something, then if you have a problem with an aspect of *your cide*, feel free to ask for help with *your code*.

Comment: Consider a new static method which returns a `String` of the expansion. This one can also be recursive.

Comment: @Bohemian I agree. It's both clear and provides an attempt. You have to read the penultimate-but-one line of code to see that, though, so I understand why you closed it.

Comment: Considering that a factorial is `n * n -1 * ... * 1` why don't you just use a `for` loop starting from `n` and going downward to 1?

Comment: @Bohemian what does make my question unlcear ? It is perfectly clear what I want to do

Comment: @krul please read my earlier comment

Comment: @Bohemian you missed my comment within the code I guess? I'm able to output 4! = 4 x 3, but unable to go down to 1

Comment: @Bohemian There is an attempt, and this is a non-trivial problem in Java because the naive method uses ridiculous amounts of memory and does lots of memory copying.

Comment: @wizz so, let’s see OP’s naive method then. Naive will still get it done. If OP has a problem with runtime, sure ask away about it.

Comment: @krul hint: one way would be to write a recursive method `printFact(int n)` and call that

Comment: @Krul Throw together a simple solution with a for loop counting down the numbers and `str += "x" + i` so we can get this question opened again.

Comment: @wizz and btw, it doesn’t have to have the problems about which you speak if such a method prints instead of returning a string.

Comment: @Bohemian That's a rather monolithic design, though, and it's best to teach best practices so you don't make all the mistakes I did. I think that's `StringBuilder` in Java?

Comment: @wizz `print("Because “ + n + "! = “ + n); printFact(n - 1);` and `void printFact(int n) {if (n == 0) {println();} else {print(" x " + n); printFact(n - 1);}}`

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help. I think I figured it out